# Meaning is in the brain, where else?

Tags: epistemology, neurophilosophy

Philosophy of languages discusses the two concepts of *extension* and *intension*. Since the 1960ies Putnam published a series of papers on topics like the meaning of meaning. He argues against the view that meaning exists in the brain only: “ ’meanings’ just aint’t in the head!” By the famous thought experiment of water on the twin earth he clarified his point of view, that the meaning of a term has to take into account more than just brain states.

In the meantime, neuroscience has established itself as a player in the domain of philosophy of mind. Some researchers with a strong capability in neurobiology and philosophy have presented new models of the mind; e.g. Gerhard Roth: Das Gehirn und seine Wirklichkeit. 1994 (in German).

The philosophical approach employs a constructivist epistemology. On the other hand, neuroscience emphasizes that the content of our mental processes solely results by pattern recognition and pattern processing from the net of neural activity in the brain. The brain is deaf and blind. It neither hears nor sees nor smells nor touches etc.

It is our cognitive system, which classifies the neural input as visual, auditive, olfactoric or sensual due to the brain areas where the input comes from and due to its time-related pattern. 
Herefrom the brain constructs a world-model with the relevant features of our environment. This world-model is permanently updated. All our perceptions refer to this model. But the model itself stays transparent. It is invisible to our conscious awareness: We perceive the inner world-model as if we had direct contact to the things from the outside world.

My thesis:

> The meaning of a term is the relation between two mental structures, both of which form part of our world-model. One structure is the pattern of the term, the other is a combination of several other patterns (the intension).

In particular, all meaning is in the brain because the world-model is in the brain.

**Added**: What are possible objections?

Comment: I see an assertion, but not a direct question.

Comment: @jowehler Thanks.  I deleted my comment because I thought I had misunderstood.  One possible objection may be that the total uniformity of the neocortex, both in physical construction and functional operation, may undermine the ability to identify *two* such mental structures as being different mental structures.

Comment: I employ the term 'mental structure' to denote an identifiable substructure of the neocortex being in  a definite state of activation. Using terms from computer science I consider it a process running in a subsystem - not only the subsystem considered as a static unit. (That's my answer to the former, now deleted comment of Nick R)

Comment: Can you restructure your question to cut to the chase a bit sooner?

Comment: If I am not already trying your patience... Kurzweil claims his view are well supported by neuroscience.  According to his view, when I read the word *cat*, a number of elementary substructures interact across a few different layers of the neocortex to enable me to identity each letter.  These composite substructures then form a unified hierarchy which enables me to understand the meaning of the word.  Forming this hierarchy introduces new interactions into the ensemble but is not a separate structure.  Odds are, I've probably misunderstood by Kurzweil and yourself!

Comment: @NickR - That's a rather gross oversimplification.  If I say "meow", you will be able to read a badly-corrupted word "cat" when you couldn't before.  There's _tons_ of top-down stuff as well as bottom-up.  Also, you can teach children to read words before you teach them the letters; they need only recognize the shape of the word enough to distinguish it from other words, not to make sure the letters are right.

Comment: @RexKerr I agree that Kurzweil's view is less than satisfactory.  To his credit though, he does include top-down as well as bottom-up interactions.  And yes, children can be taught differently, but K's abstraction should account for these variations if applied differently.

Comment: Your position seems to be one of indirect/representative realism. The alternative 'direct realist' stance would have all the objections you're looking for (?).

Comment: In case you employ 'direct realist' a synonym for 'naive realist': Do you consider direct realism a valid epistemology?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking *is the meaning in your head all in your head*, then of course the answer is yes.  (I'm going to leave aside the details of your formulation, because it is specific to a degree that goes beyond what can be validated with present-day neuroscience.)

But that misses the point of the twin-earth thought experiment.  I don't think it's the best thought-experiment, but it's widely known, so let's go with it for now.

In brief, suppose there is a twin earth where everything is identical *and functions identically at a superficial level* but where H<sub>2</sub>O is absent and there is a substance XYZ instead (which everyone there calls "water").

Now, in a sense, "water", being all in the head of both Earthlings and Twinlings (let's call them), are exactly the same thing, because they are the same thing-to-them.  In particular, their mental states might be completely indistinguishable from each other, and thus we'd say that the meanings are indistinguishable.

But in another sense, they are *not* the same because the substances *are* distinguishable (though not presently to Earthlings and Twinlings) and Earthlings mean H<sub>2</sub>O and Twinlings mean XYZ.  And this is a *very important* sense of meaning since we have to interact with the outside world.  We expect that meanings like those conveyed by "water" will attach naturally to whatever additional things we find out about water including whether it's actually H<sub>2</sub>O or XYZ.

So after considering Putnam's argument one can accept your thesis *and yet want more*, which is to also have a theory of how many different brains can refer to the same (and/or different) external entities.  The purely internal account makes that exquisitely difficult.

(Yes, you eventually have to get there by considering how the models built by your brain end up with an expectation of various invariants including that XYZ isn't quite what we mean by "water", but adding that extra layer of interpretation makes the logical structure harder to see.)

Comment: All agree that meaning is a semantic relation between a term and something which is in question.
My point is: The semantic relation resides completely in our brain. It is a relation within our world-model. But in addition and first, there is a causal relation. It relates the real-world things of our environment to the input of our sensory organs. This physical relation has no semantics. The semantics originates when our brain detects and stores in memory certain recurrent patterns from the time-related neuronal input.

Comment: Semantics is the result when transforming the physical relation into a relation of the world-model. 
Hence I consider Putnams Ansatz a bit outdated, because he does not discriminate between the two relations. I agree, that the cloned observers on earth and on twin earth construct the same world-model, i.e. they are in the same psychological state – in Putnams words. And concerning the causal relation, Putnam may also assume that the two different liquids on earth and on twin earth affect the sensory organs of both clones in the same way.

Comment: After disentangling accordingly Putnam’s thought experiment in two quite different relations, is there a remaining problem? But probably you can expand a bit your second to last and your last section.

Comment: @jowehler - Semantic relations may reside completely in our brains, but how they get there?  Our brains are good at picking up external cues and translating them into internal semantic relations (and this happens reliably across people), so in some sense the _real_ relationship is the external one and what's in our brains is just the details of what we need to do to notice the relationship.  Then one has to ask which words one wants to use to mean the internal implementation details vs. the external relationships--Putnam seems to favor "semantics" covering the latter as well.

Comment: @jowehler Somebody mentions the twin paradox and I recall that it is explained by relativity. I do not remember the details, but I know where to look them up, it gets clearer when I do. The next day an expert friend gives me a primer on relativity. Did my meaning of "relativity" change through the process, is it different from my friend's? Putnam thinks not, and he has a point. Mental states are individual, meaning is social, mental states are in flux, meaning is invariant. Neuroscience may be able to correlate mental states to brain activity, but neither represents what meaning is.

Comment: @RexKerr: It seems we agree on the main points: There are two relations, a physical (or real) one between the real-world things and certain components of our world-model. And a semantic relation between the latter components and the term-component of the word-model. Putnam considered only the composite relation, terming it ‘meaning’. My point are not the names of each relation.

Comment: @RexKerr: In my opinion, only a constructivist epistemology gives right attention to the concept of a world-model and its importance for ‘Representation and Reality’. The only proponent of such a constructivist view in the context of neurobiology, of whom I know, is Gerhard Roth.

Comment: @Conifold: For me it is obvious, that your meaning of the term ‘relativity’ changes when you learn more about the Special Theory of Relativity. Your meaning expands, in the end it comprises more aspects than before. At present, your meaning consists of a vague agglomeration of pieces from a story about two twins who experience a different flow of time. Also, at present your meaning of ‘relativity’ differs from your friend’s meaning of the term.

Comment: @Conifold: My first aim is not to give a rational reconstruction of meaning in the global sense. Today as a first approximation, I am satisfied with proposing what the meaning for a single person could be, i.e. reconstructing the concept of ‘individual meaning’.

Comment: @jo wehler I am afraid that language is a social game, and "meaning" as normally used is inherently intersubjective. Why not just use "mental state" to avoid the confusion. In any case, trying to interpret it as "meaning" runs into all sorts of problems with psychologism http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/psychologism/, anomalism of the mental http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/anomalous-monism/ and inscrutability of reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscrutability_of_reference

Comment: @jo wehler Putnam in particular claims that due to the latter the correspondence theory of truth fails every time one tries to apply it, and the idea that we refer with our sentences and statements to a mind-independent world is an illusion. Because "mind-independent world"  presupposes distinct referential relations from language to objects, while referential objects of language are inscrutable.

Comment: @Conifold: Surfing the sources you recommend I found a paper of David Rose: Three Dimensions on Psychosemantics. Gestalt Theory 2012, Vol. 34, No.3/4, 259-286. The author starts his summary "To understand the meaning of ‘meaning’ and whether the concept can be applied at subpersonal levels, its nature must first be elucidated. Full understanding of psychosemantics requires a three-dimensional state-space of possible explanations, with axes (1) atomismholism, (2) synchronic-diachronic functionality, and (3) level of analysis." Possibly that's the right field to locate my original question.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would suggest that meaning is intersubjective; this gets away from the notion of Descartian subjectivity which is self-subsistent; requiring no other.

This is Lacans distinct contribution to modern European philosophy (through his notion of the Mirror, which is just his allegorical method of re-introducing this truth; the face of the mother, or father being the 'mirror' in which we see ourselves; where we resolve a Unity of Apperception at the level of subjects; not of sensations - a la Kant).

(Unger takes this further, he grounds freedom in this acceptance).

In this picture, Crusoe on his isle, alone; would not survive for twenty years to return to the life-world; but his unity as a subject would dissolve; one cannot say *disrupt*; as nothing has *acted* on him to disrupt him; unless one goes along with Sartre (in *Nausea*) and say pure *nothingness* can act in this way.

In a different tradition, say Native Americans; aloneness is not the conditions for nothingness, as such; but to enter into a different dimension of being; the spirit world (see *Black Elk Speaks*). A parallel here might be with Rilkes *Sonnets to Orpheus*:

> There rose a tree! O pure transcendence!
>
> O Orpheus sings! O tall tree in the ear!
>
> And all was silent. Yet still in this silence
>
> Proceeded new beginning, sign or transformation

So, we can say meaning is both *in* Subjects and *between* Subjects.

And then of course we have the very difficult question of what is the origin of Subjecivity; which pours both light and darkness on what constitutes meaning in the world.

Comment: Speaking of intersubjectivity, jo wehler reminded me of Husserl since his position looks like a form of psychologism, and Husserl criticized it so passionately in v.1 of Logical Investigations. http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/psychologism/#HusAntArg